# Devise w/ OmniAuth or straight up Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I currently have a simple, hand-coded login system in my rails app. Now, I'm looking to integrate Facebook login via OmniAuth (seems to be the best way to do so)

However, I keep seeing Devise come up as a popular way to handle logins, with OmniAuth implemented in conjunction with it.

If I'm pretty happy with my login system now, is there any reason to use Devise? Does it give OmniAuth any extra functionality/extensibility or make it easier to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a railscasts subscriber check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised

Devise does have some convenient hooks for omniauth, so that is a plus to using devise. That being said if you are happy with your authentication then you can simply build omniauth as a separate authentication method, and handle any overlap yourself. Also check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth.

Good luck!